# Why am I getting 'Subquery returns more than 1row' error in my UNION ALL query?

Tags: mysql, union-all

My query is like this:

```
SELECT 0 AS CNT1
      , COUNT(*) AS CNT2
FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT CANCEL_DTM FROM TR_LST_TABLE TLT2
            WHERE TLT1.CANCEL_NO = TLT2.PURCHASE_NO) CANCEL_DTM 
           , TLT1.PURCHASE_DTM
    FROM TR_LST_TABLE TLT1
    WHERE TLT1.CLSS = 'CANCEL'
) A
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A.CANCEL_DTM,'%m') != DATE_FORMAT(A.PURCHASE_DTM,'%m')
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT1
      , 0 AS CNT2
FROM FROM TR_LST_TABLE TLT1
WHERE TLT1.CLSS = 'PURCHASE'
```

By separating UNION ALL, both queries normally come out in the form I want as follows.

```
CNT1              CNT2
----------------------
some number    some number
```

Then, if you do UNION ALL, I think it should come out in the form below,

```
CNT1              CNT2
----------------------
some number    some number
some number    some number
```

However, I do not understand why the error 'Subquery returns more than 1row' is emitted when UNION ALL is performed.

When I looked at my query, 'WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A.CANCEL_DTM,'%m') != DATE_FORMAT(A.PURCHASE_DTM,'%m')' If I don't have this part, I get the result I wanted, but I need a WHERE clause.

Is there any usage of UNION ALL query that I am not aware of?

Comment: I can't think of any way that `UNION` could cause this error. I suspect the data changed and it's just coincidence that it worked when you ran the queries separately.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows in `TR_LST_TABLE` with the same `CANCEL_NO`? That will cause the `SELECT CANCEL_DTM` subquery to return multiple rows, causing this error.

Comment: Thanks for posting a comment. first, I understand that you are saying that an error occurs in the subquery.
However, CANCEL_NO does not produce multiple lines.

Comment: And I don't understand UNION. Aren't both queries executed independently and then merged?

Comment: Yes, that's how UNION works.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier question should have been about duplicate `PURCHASE_NO`.

Comment: In my table, PURCHASE_NO is a KEY value, so I don't think it can be duplicated.

Comment: And I can't understand the error. As you said, if the problem is that multiple rows occur in a subquery, shouldn't an error occur even if there is no WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, this is very confusing. It seems like a bug, or maybe a corrupted index.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think you should check the index again.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at a site like sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Since the working environment is a closed network, there are many restrictions, so I will check and ask again. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can get to this website, you should be able to get to that one. I'm not asking you to copy production data to it.

Comment: I think put "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A.CANCEL_DTM,'%m') != DATE_FORMAT(A.PURCHASE_DTM,'%m')" inside () A replacing "WHERE" with "AND".